# How can click an option if SELECT list is define in a div with Selenium-webdriver & Java

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

In the below code ,i want to click on Baseball game option, but i am unable to click on it

HTML CODE

```
    <option value="" disabled="" selected="">-- Choose Option --</option>


    <option value="12">Baseball Game</option>

    <option value="1417">Practice</option>

</select>
</div>
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this is just the HTML Code, you haven't provide your Java Snippet.
Below is an example of how to go about selecting your options

1)

```
  driver.findyElementBy(By.Xpath("//option[@value='Baseball Game']")).click();
```

2)

```
  WebElement selectElement = driver.findElementBy(By.tagName("select"));
  Select selectOption = new Select(selectElement);
  selectOption.selectByValue("Baseball Game");
```